# XNA How to show "gold" highlight around available selections

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm trying to figure out a way with a pixel shader or some other method to show the "available" options to select from. I suppose making another pixel art and layering it could do the trick but I was just curious if there are other means. I tried searching for "pixel shader highlighting" but got no where. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please provide some code so that we can better help you.  There are tons of ways to accomplish this.  Your lowest overhead will just be drawing two separate pictures rather than trying to use shaders just for some text / options.  No reason to solve this problem with a bazooka!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a sprite you can just draw it twice:

1. slightly larger and colored;
2. overlayed, as before.

This will give you the effect of a colored border.
It might or might not look good, but maybe it's worth a try.

You can also do the inverse: the deactivated options colored black or gray, but here I'm fantasizing and diverging.

If you post a pic maybe someone can give you more ideas.